# Адаптивное меню не работает

Tags: html, bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar-white sticky-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-targer="#navbarSupport"></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul style="background-color: #e7e7e7" class="navbar-nav justify-content-center p-4">
      <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3 nav-item active"><a id="lel" class="nav-link" href="index.html">НА ГЛАВНУЮ</a></li>
      <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3 nav-item active"><a id="lel" class="nav-link" href="rashet.html">РАСЧЁТ СТОИМОСТИ</a></li>
      <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3 nav-item active"><a id="lel" class="nav-link" href="zakaz.html">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a></li>
      <div class="navbar-brand ml-5">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" width="80"></a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Пропали все кнопки или почему не работает адаптивное меню?

Comment: Исправил,не помогло.

Comment: Тааак,я тут понял у меня всё очень криво написано.В общем написал туда 123 появились только они но меню ещё нету.

Comment: '<nav class="navbar-expand-white sticky-top" >' тоже не работает.

Comment: Нет, нет, нет. Что Вы такое пишите? Смотрите..

Answer (score 1):

Вы перепутали `navbar-white` и `navbar-light`, `data-targer` и `data-target`.
Забыли подключить **js** для корректной работы меню. Оставили тег `button` пустым. Указали неверное **id** для `data-target`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul style="background-color: #e7e7e7" class="navbar-nav justify-content-center p-4">
      <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3 nav-item active"><a id="lel" class="nav-link" href="index.html">НА ГЛАВНУЮ</a></li>
      <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3 nav-item active"><a id="lel" class="nav-link" href="rashet.html">РАСЧЁТ СТОИМОСТИ</a></li>
      <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3 nav-item active"><a id="lel" class="nav-link" href="zakaz.html">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a></li>
      <div class="navbar-brand ml-5">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" width="80"></a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```